# Touchpad scrolling stopped working after Debian 9 upgrade

Tags: debian, upgrade, touchpad

I have upgraded my Debian 8 to Debian 9 and found out that side touchpad scrolling stopped working on my Lenono G560. Has anyone experienced something similar?

[I found that](https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad)

> The synaptic Xorg driver in being superseded by the newer libinput
>   driver, which can provide lower-level access to multi touch events to
>   clients, but is currently lacking some features found in the older
>   driver.
>
> You can make the `synaptics` driver take precedence over `libinput` by copying 
>   `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` into `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`, so 
>   as to make it take precendence over the `libinput` configuration file found 
>   at `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf`.

Yet after doing those steps the problem persists.